# Abort from the middle of a pipe in a zsh script

Tags: shell, zsh

I have a somewhat complex pipe in a zsh script that looks like this

```
comm -23 \
    <( git ... ) \
    <( git ... |
        sed ... ) | ...
```

Now, if either of the git commands fail, I want to quit my script early. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would just split the command into multiple lines. There's no need to even start `comm` if either `git` fails.

```
trap 'rm -f tmp1 tmp2' EXIT
git ... > tmp1 || exit
git ... | sed ... > tmp2 || exit
trap - EXIT
comm -23 tmp1 tmp2 | ...
```

The calls to `trap` are optional, if you want the temporary files removed if either `git` fails.

Comment: Well, I don't want to create temporary files. Does the `<()` redirection allow `comm` to start reading the output before the output is complete (since it just passes a file descriptor), or does `comm` just wait for the entire output first? (although, really, that's just theory, since I pipe the output of the git commands to `sort` anyways, which does buffer all of the input.)

Comment: What's wrong with temporary files? `comm` can start reading as soon as something is available, but `sort` won't output anything until `git` completes.